# Finding multiple accounts under the same name for Python bank system

Tags: python-3.x, function, for-loop, error-handling, syntax-error

In my bank system I have a set of customer accounts but for one name Adam Smith he has two accounts:

```
def load_bank_data(self):

    # the customers in the bank system
    account_no = 1234
    customer_1 = CustomerAccount("Adam", "Smith", 14, "Wilcot Street", "Bath", "B5 5RT", account_no, "Current", 2500.00)
    self.accounts_list.append(customer_1)

    account_no += 5678
    customer_2 = CustomerAccount("David", "White", 60, "Holburn Viaduct", "London", "EC1A 2FD", account_no, "Savings", 3200.00)
    self.accounts_list.append(customer_2)

    account_no += 3456
    customer_3 = CustomerAccount("Alice", "Churchil", 55, "Cardigan Street", "Birmingham", "B4 7BD", account_no, "Current", 18000.00)
    self.accounts_list.append(customer_3)

    account_no += 6789
    customer_4 = CustomerAccount("Ali", "Abdallah", 44, "Churchill Way West", "Basingstoke", "RG21 6YR", account_no, "Savings", 40.00)
    self.accounts_list.append(customer_4)

    account_no += 1987
    customer_5 = CustomerAccount("Adam", "Smith", 44, "Churchill Way West", "Basingstoke", "RG21 6YR", account_no, "Savings", 5000.00)
    self.accounts_list.append(customer_5)
```

I created a function so when many customer accounts under the same first and last name have been found, it should add all those bank account balances together and print out the final total. (The input is where I type the customer to find multiple accounts for:

```
def sum_of_all_money(self):
    try:

        find_customer = input("Enter the surname of the customer to find total sum of money for: ")

        for find_customer in self.accounts_list:
            find_customer = find_customer.get_balance() + find_customer.get_balance()
        print(find_customer)

    except SyntaxError as e:
        print(e)
```

This is only just finding one Adam Smith account at the bottom as customer 5 but it doesn't detect the other Adam Smith account as customer 1 and it just adds customer 5 twice giving me an output of 1000.00 which isn't right, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're using `find_customer` in two different ways: as input, and as an object iterated over your accounts list.

Comment: Ok, I took out the input and it now displays all the balances for every customer, would an __add__ class be suitable for adding the two Adam Smith balances together?

Comment: Don't you first need an `if` conditional to check that the account belongs to a Smith?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has some flaws, currently it will only loop over your list and always overwrite `find_customer` with the current balance of the customer * 2.

You need to filter for the right name which was input, try it like this:

```
try:

    find_customer = input("Enter the surname of the customer to find total sum of money for: ")

    find_customer_balance = 0

    for customer in self.accounts_list:
        if customer.get_surname() == find_customer:
           find_customer_balance += customer.get_balance()
    print(find_customer)
    print(find_customer_balance)

except SyntaxError as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: Oh yes that's it, thank you so much. I was just struggling to find out how to get Python to filter through the customer names and find the matching ones.